# Firebase Rules allows read but does not allow write

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
"display": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
        "abc": {
          ".indexOn": ["hhh"],
          "$display_id": {
            "aaa": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "bbb": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "ccc": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "ddd": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "eee": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "fff": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "ggg": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "hhh": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "iii": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "jjj": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
            "kkk": {".validate": "newData.val() == $display_id"},
            "lll": {".validate": "newData.isNumber()"},
            "$others": {".validate": false}
            }
        }
}
```

The above code is a snippet of one of my path rules in the Firebase Database Rules section.

Just for reference, `display_id` is a pushed value and `lll` is a long which is obtained from `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`.

I have been trying to find the solution for this for a long time and I’m on the verge of giving up.

These are my few observations up until now.

1. There are no `.read` or `.write` above the “display” in the rule tree, so there should not be any cascading errors regarding reading or writing the data.
2. There shouldn’t be any problems in my App’s java class model since I can read the data fine
3. There shouldn’t be any authentication errors since I can read the data with `auth != null`
4. There should not be any annotation errors as the rules applet does not give me any errors at the moment

I’m lost. When I write data to this node through my app, I keep getting Permission Denied.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please update your question to include the write operation that is giving problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late update! I managed to solve this problem. Apologies if I didn't post the block of code needed.

The problem is unfortunately a cascading problem, and I must have misunderstood it for some reason.

If I were to put a read and write rule at a specific node, I must reference at least from that specific node, and I wish the documentation could be clearer but after realizing this error everything worked perfectly!

So for example if I have a database structure that is something like this:

```
"display": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null",
    "abc": {
      ".indexOn": ["hhh"],
      "$display_id": {
        "aaa": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "bbb": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "ccc": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "ddd": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "eee": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "fff": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "ggg": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "hhh": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "iii": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "jjj": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"},
        "kkk": {".validate": "newData.val() == $display_id"},
        "lll": {".validate": "newData.isNumber()"},
        "$others": {".validate": false}
        }
    }
}
```

in my code, I should write this immediately before trying to act on the query for that node (writing this in onCreate() would be helpful):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("display") //reference immediately to the "display" node, where you intend to put the read and write rules;
```

Hope this helps, and apologies for the huge misunderstanding of the Firebase Rules documentation.